# How can I exclude controller name from the virtual path when I use Server.MapPath()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I call Server.MapPath() from MyController's action method to generate a virtual path to a particular file stored in a folder called Templates:

```
Server.MapPath($"Templates/{pdfFileName}")
```

MapPath() returns a path like this:

```
C:\SomePath\MyApp\MyController\Templates\MyFile.pdf
```

This is not good, as the actual path should be

```
C:\SomePath\MyApp\Templates\MyFile.pdf
```

How to get the right path? Thanks.

Comment: What about `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"Templates/{pdfFileName}");` or `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"Templates/{pdfFileName}");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the first option returns Templates/MyFile.pdf. And HttpContext has no Current...

Comment: What about this? `string path = 
 Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/Templates/" + pdfFileName)); file.SaveAs(path);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `~`:
for example:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/Templates/" + pdfFileName));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I need!